# Вызов метода в классе

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как можно в Vue.js вызвать метод в классе? Например у меня есть метод который возвращает какое-то текстовое значение и я хочу в HTML класс вывести его.

Comment: Вы хотите чтоб функция возвращала какой то класс для html элемента?

Comment: Да, чтобы функция передавала какое-либо значение и оно попадало в шаблон HTML в область класса блока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

```
<div :class="someFunc">
  ...
</div>
```

Далее в computed создаем функцию в которую передаем массив классов и/или объект, если нужно еще и условия добавить

```
computed: {
  ...
  someFunc() {
    return [
       {
         'xochuTakoyClassIf': this.isNeedClass,
       },
       'aEtotClassBudetVsegda'
     ]
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать вот тут https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html